# Suppress stdout from check_output but write it to a log instead

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, stdout

I have the following code:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(command.split())
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    count_failure.increment()
    logger.error(e.__dict__)
    return
```

When `check_output()` fails, then I would like to suppress that message from stdout, but write it to my `logger` instead.

Right now the stdout error message messes up my `tqdm` progress bar:

```
[hobbes3@hobbes3 bin]$ ./mass_index.py
34%|█████████████████████████████████████████▋                                                                                | 13/38 [00:00<00:14,  1.75it/s]
unable to open file: path='/mnt/data/samples/irs_990/foo.xml' error='Permission denied'
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 38/38 [00:02<00:00,  5.96it/s]
```

Also, the actual message `Permission denied` isn't stored inside `e`. My `e.__dict__` only says

```
{'returncode': 22, 'cmd': ['/opt/splunk/bin/splunk', 'add', 'oneshot', '/mnt/data/samples/irs_990/foo.xml', '-index', 'main', '-sourcetype', 'irs_990'], 'output': b'', 'stderr': None}
```

Comment: redirect `stderr` ? `subprocess.check_output(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that is because the command you're running is issuing error messages to standard error stream.

`check_output` only captures standard *output*, unless you use an extra parameter. So either:

```
subprocess.check_output(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

so errors are also in the output, or (python 3):

```
subprocess.check_output(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

to suppress this error message completely.

To get a proper exception message with standard error in it, you would have to redirect error stream to a specific pipe so you wouldn't have `stderr=None`

```
subprocess.check_output(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But that could cause deadlocks between output and error streams (depending on how the program outputs to output or error, if the pipes aren't read in a smart way (ex: with threading), one write could block because of buffer full while you're reading the other one which is empty).

Maybe in your case you'd be better off with `subprocess.Popen` and `communicate` which handles that case nicely (with threads or whatever works underneath)

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error = p.communicate()
```

(and keep the same exception handling)

Comment: How do I capture the exact message `unable to open file: path='/mnt/data/samples/irs_990/foo.xml' error='Permission denied'` to `logger` then?

Comment: Never mind, `e` is getting the entire error now: `2018-12-06 21:51:40 [ERROR  ] (Thread-11 ) {'returncode': 22, 'cmd': ['/opt/splunk/bin/splunk', 'add', 'oneshot', '/mnt/data/samples/irs_990/foo.xml', '-index', 'main', '-sourcetype', 'irs_990'], 'output': b"unable to open file: path='/mnt/data/samples/irs_990/foo.xml' error='Permission denied'\n", 'stderr': None}`. Thanks!

Comment: if you're fine with error coming stdout, then it's okay. Else I have provided more alternatives

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why redirecting error stream to the pipe would cause deadlock?

Comment: depending on how the program outputs to output or error, if the pipes aren't read in a smart way (ex: with threading), one write could block because of buffer full while you're reading the other one which is empty. It _could_ cause deadlock, not 100% all the time